# Minutes(Integer) conversion to Hours(Float) in HH.MM format in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to convert Minutes (`integer`) values in to Hours `float` (HH.MM) in SQL Server 2008.
for example  398 Minutes get converted into 6.38 Hours, 419 Minutes get converted into 6.59 hours etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please try:

```
SELECT 398 / 60 + (398 % 60) / 100.0
SELECT 419 / 60 + (419 % 60) / 100.0
```

specific

```
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(18, 2), 398 / 60 + (398 % 60) / 100.0)
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(18, 2), 419 / 60 + (419 % 60) / 100.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned method fails when a decimal number is given though i'm not sure whether your application needs a decimal value.

```
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(18, 2), 90.90 / 60 + (90.90 % 60) / 100.0)
```

> > 1.82

try

```
select dateadd(minute,398,0)
```