# Sum of hour and minutes in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have written one query,but it not giving correct answer.I want to display like this
 5 Hour 58 minutes + 7 Hour 58 minutes=13 hour 56 minutes(answer should `13.56`),but this below query giving `15.09` .

Please reply me with any other solution.(here `Effort1` is 5 Hour column,`Effort1Minutes` is 58 minute column and same  `Effort2`  is 7 Hour column,`Effort2Minutes` is 58 minute column .

```
 select CAST((SUM(Effort1)*60+SUM(Effort1Minutes))/60 as float) +  
       (CAST((SUM(Effort1)*60+SUM(Effort1Minutes))% 60 as float)) / 100 +   
        CAST((SUM(Effort2)*60+SUM(Effort2Minutes))/60 as float) +  
       (CAST((SUM(Effort2)*60+SUM(Effort2Minutes))% 60 as float)) / 100               
 from TimesheetDetails
```

Comment: Does this provide help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16662784/minutesinteger-conversion-to-hoursfloat-in-hh-mm-format-in-sql-server-2008?rq=1

Comment: The problem isn't easily solved in SQL Server - do you have to solve it there? SQL Server has a `time` data type, but that's for a time of day, rather than for an interval - and what you're doing here is really adding two intervals together - so whilst it may be possible to bodge something together (assuming you never overflow 24 hours) it would be better done in a language that does have a proper type representing the concepts that you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

please tried below query

```
    select CONVERT(decimal(18,2),SUM(Effort1 + Effort2)) + 
    SUM(Effort1Minutes + Effort2Minutes) / 60 + 
    CONVERT(decimal(18,2), (SUM(Effort1Minutes + Effort2Minutes) % 60) / 100.00)
from TimesheetDetails
```

I had tested with this query with SQL server 2008 as well as with [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/24cbf/4)

Comment: Dear Naresh,I ahve tried your code which one you posted in top. its not giving correct answer(13.6-this is not correct answer). Answer should be 13.56 , my question is 5 Hour 58 minutes + 7 Hour 58 minutes=13 hour 56 minutes(answer should 13.56).please reply me with some other solution.

Comment: what is datatype of Effort1,  Effort2, Effort1Minutes and Effort2Minutes ?

Comment: Effort1, Effort2 are decimal(3, 1) and Effort1Minutes,Effort2Minutes are int datatype

Comment: please try with latest query

Comment: Dear Naresh,I dint get latest query . please post with latest query.

Comment: I had edited that sql query.. please use above query and sql fiddle.

Comment: Thanks alot.its woking now

Comment: Thanks God, it works for you, please up vote  and mark as answer